# Extracting element after another element with xpath/beautiful soup

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

[image]

I'm looking for a robust way to extract both team names and market odds. Given the above code segment this would be

West Brom
Man City
28/1
6/1
1/8

I should also mention that I would only need team names and market odds AFTER a given fixture id (which is located in the 'data-fixtureid' attribute).

I have tried the following xpath expression:

```
    tree.xpath('//span[@class="ippg-Market_Truncator"]/following::div[@data-fixtureid="66705048"]//text()')
```

to extract the team names, which didn't result in the desired output.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. I don't necessarily need to use xpath for this, but could also use beautiful soup for example.

Comment: Can you paste the link?

Comment: No, not the link -- the actual (relevant, subset) HTML.  The question should be able to stand on its own, without the link, the contents for which could change or become unavailable in the future.

Comment: @AndMar, I guess OP means [this page](https://mobile.bet365.com/?apptype=&appversion=&cb=1505939716#type=Coupon;key=1-1-13-33601911-2-1-0-0-1-0-0-4100-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0;ip=0;lng=1;anim=1)

Comment: Thank you, Andersson. This page as an alternative https://mobile.bet365.com/#type=Coupon;key=1-1-13-33577327-2-1-0-0-1-0-0-4100-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0;ip=0;lng=1;anim=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is different from xpath since I used `find_all()` and `find()` functions to achieve your desired result.

First, I look for all the rows you need with a class name `podEventRow`

Second, I loop through that list and looked for the team name with class `ippg-Market_CompetitorName` then strip/replace unnecessary whitespaces.

Third, inside the same loop I looked for the market odds using the class name `ippg-Market_Topic` and then loop through each odds to get the text inside each.

```
podEventRow = soup.find_all('div', class_="podEventRow")
for row in podEventRow:
    team_name = row.find('div', class_="ippg-Market_CompetitorName").get_text(strip=True).replace('\t\r\n', '')
    market_odds_raw = row.find_all('div', class_="ippg-Market_Topic")
    market_odds = ''
    for odd in market_odds_raw:
        market_odds += ' - ' + odd.get_text(strip=True).replace('\t\r\n', '')
    print(team_name + market_odds)
```

PS: I used selenium to get the complete page source since the site uses JavaScript to load the table.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is close to perfect! In your code only the first team name is extracted for each match, but with your suggestion I'm sure I can find a way to also extract the second team name.

Comment: I should mention your code also extracts the team names/market odds for leagues that are collapsed/hidden by default. E.g. 'Copa Libertadores' here https://mobile.bet365.com/#type=Coupon;key=1-1-13-40-140-0-0-0-1-0-0-4100-0-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0;ip=0;lng=1;anim=1 which is fantastic!